# Keras conv2D input shape error. Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (58, 195, 1)

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I face issue regarding inputshape. During the model.fit(), I get an value error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array 
with shape (58, 195, 1)
```

```
    num_columns=195 #features
    train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], num_columns,1)#array of size 11252. i.e 58*195
    test_x = test_x.reshape(test_x.shape[0], num_columns,1)#array size 18*195
    valid_x=valid_x.reshape(valid_x.shape[0], num_columns,1) #array size 22*195

    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(58,195,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

Is there a way to deal with this? I also tried reshaping data as (-1,58,195,1). It didn't work

Comment: What is that you're trying to do? Is this image data or just numerical data? E.g. Do you have 58 samples with 195 features? Or a set of images with (58, 195) dimensions?

Comment: So your data consists of 58 samples with 195 features each? If so, you don't provide the size of your dataset to the `input_shape`. Can you try `(195,1)` instead?

Comment: When I tried with (195,1)  as input_shape, I got this ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Comment: Yes, each of 58 data has 195 features. The data is not a image, its a audio file

Comment: If your data is audio, you could use `Conv1D`.

Comment: Yes I have used Conv1D

Comment: I don't think you have. Error is at this line `model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape=(58,195,1)))` Conv2D expects 4 dims, you have 3. Hence use Conv1D